# Как в asp.net core создать страницу "сайт на обслуживании"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

О хороших практиках в asp.net core.

Хочу создать на Home контроллере отдельный Action Maintainance, который будет показывать заранее заготовленную страницу сайт на обслуживании.

Как реализовать включение/выключение подобной страницы в asp.net core? Есть ли какой-то готовый способ?

Comment: сорри, нет времени написать подробный ответ, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#app_offlinehtm

Comment: @PashaPash, времени на ответ не появилось? '@AK, может вы уже решили задачу? Напишете ответ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я обычно не рассчитываю, что на so ответят быстро, поэтому нет, ещё не делал: неделя длинная, с рабочей субботой - буду смотреть на первые майские.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955500/regarding-maintenance-mode-in-asp-net-core и https://rimdev.io/middleware-madness-site-maintenance-in-aspnet-core/, т.е. использовать QueryFilter или Middleware.

Comment: а статика тут не подойдёт или это не очень хорошая практика?

Comment: @PashaPash, что там с ответом? :)

Answer (score 6):

Все ленятся, а по [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#app_offlinehtm) внезапно простое и приятное решение.

> If a file with the name app_offline.htm is detected in the root
>   directory of an app, the ASP.NET Core Module attempts to gracefully
>   shutdown the app and stop processing incoming requests. If the app is
>   still running after the number of seconds defined in
>   shutdownTimeLimit, the ASP.NET Core Module kills the running process.
>
> While the app_offline.htm file is present, the ASP.NET Core Module
>   responds to requests by sending back the contents of the
>   app_offline.htm file. When the app_offline.htm file is removed, the
>   next request starts the app.

Т.е. нужно создать файл app_offline.htm с нужным сообщением для пользователей и положить его в корень вашего asp.net приложения.

Приложение будет остановлено, все запросы пользователей будут пересылаться на страницу.
Как только файл будет удалён - доступ к приложению будет снова восстановлен.

---

> Как реализовать включение/выключение подобной страницы в asp.net core?

С учетом того, что приложение останавливается - делать придётся вне приложения любым удобным способом - руками, отдельным приложением, скриптом.

---

Как справедливо отметили, и как пишет МС:

> The ASP.NET Core Module is a native IIS module that plugs into the IIS
>   pipeline to forward web requests to backend ASP.NET Core apps.

Так что, к сожалению, это не кроссплатформенное решение, работает только с IIS.

Comment: Укажите, что это только для хостинга в IIS. У меня на линуксовых хостингах этот способ не работает ни в какую. А вот IIS Express понимает - поэтому [при запуске из visual studio даже браузер не откроется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTrds.png).

Answer (score 4):

Создайте в вашем проекте файл MaintenanceMiddleware:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class MaintenanceMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MaintenanceMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this._next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (IsMaintenance())
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 503;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Maintenance");
            }
            else
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }

        private bool IsMaintenance()
        {
            // TODO Read from DB, from file on disk etc.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Это middleware, которая либо будет пропускать запрос, либо останавливать выполнение обработки запроса с выдачей некоторого текста и HTTP кода 503 (Можно редиректить на какую-то заранее заготовленную страницу)

На ваше усмотрение, какое поставить условие для запуска режима обслуживания - либо проверить значение в базе данных, либо проверить наличие/отсутствие файла на диске.

Не забудьте включить ваш класс в Startup.cs:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<MaintenanceMiddleware>();
```