# C# ASP.NET MVC. Как перенаправить пользователя в зависимости от его роли?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Наверно банальный вопрос.
Сейчас у меня около 12 страниц(по контроллеру на каждый) и у контроллеров указан атрибут `[Authorize(Roles="Учитель")]`. Делаю вторую часть сайта для учеников, и их можно так же разграничить на `[Authorize(Roles="Ученик")]`.
Но как сделать чтобы если, скажем, ученик попытался зайти на ссылки учителя - его редиректило к себе в личный кабинет, а если учитель на ссылки ученика - его редиректило только к себе?

Можно убрать атрибут `Authorize` и проверять роли в каждом контроллере по отдельности `User.IsInRole`, но вдруг есть способ нескольким проще?

Answer (score 1):

Лично я не понимаю подобные истории, когда требования идут с некоторым запасом. "Запрещено входить ученику в личный кабинет учителя" — звучит логично. "Запрещено входить ученику в личный кабинет учителя, а ещё надо редиректить на его личный кабинет, а ещё нужно уведомить директора о попытке входа" — уже как-то избыточно. Поэтому я бы для начала обсудил бы "а надо ли вообще подобное реализовывать?"

Если же вот прям очень надо — то в зависимости от версии asp.net mvc / core вам надо либо смотреть в сторону фильтров авторизации https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.3.php либо в сторону middleware. (Вот тут например: [Как в asp.net core создать страницу "сайт на обслуживании"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/818421/213987) , по аналогии легко напишете)

PS Если у вас прям так чётко есть кабинет учителя и ученика - посмотрите в сторону `area`, возможно понравится: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/11.9.php